# Nested Links not working in Mozilla, IE, and Edge

Tags: html, nested, anchor

I am having a slight issue with my HTML due to improper nesting. When attempting to click my links in Chrome it properly anchors to a set point. However, in Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, and Edge it does not. In fact it seems as if the link is disabled. How would I go about cleaning up my nesting to fix this issue?

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background: #2e2e2e;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

*{
    transition: .3s;
}

#abt{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#hero{
    height: 50%;
    min-height:400px;
    width: 100vw;
    background: url("imgs/space2.gif");
    background-size: 11%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    z-index: -1;
}

#hero h3 img{
    height: 1em;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: skewY(3deg);
}

#hero h1{
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color: rgb(245, 251, 255);
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1.5vh;
    font-weight: 100;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #d1d1d1,
               0 2px 0 #909090,
               0 3px 0 #626161;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    margin-right: 5vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
        -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(3deg);
    transform: skewY(3deg);
}

#hero h3{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: rgb(245, 251, 255);
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 100;
          text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #d1d1d1,
               0 2px 0 #909090,
               0 3px 0 #626161;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
            -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(3deg);
    transform: skewY(3deg);
}

#options{
    margin-top: 5vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 3vh;
    margin-top: 3vh;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
            -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(3deg);
    transform: skewY(3deg);
}

#options button{
    color: rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.92);
    background: rgb(245, 251, 255);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="backdrop">
  <div id="hero">
    <h1>Haca</h1>
    <h3>Student</h3>
    <div id="options">
      <a href="#abt" alt="link">About Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="abt">About Section</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For your z index in your #hero id, you need to change it to something other than -1. I just turned it off and it works. Let me know if that solves it for you. New CSS should look like this:

```
#hero{
    height: 50%;
    min-height:400px;
    width: 100vw;
    background: url("imgs/space2.gif");
    background-size: 11%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
}
```

Comment: That would make sense! Omg thank you. I'll test this out shortly.